# Python Subprocess : Launch script in a 32 bits conda environment from a 64 bits environment

Tags: python, subprocess, environment, conda

I'm trying to launch, from a python 64 bits conda environment, another python script within a 32 bits conda environment on Windows 7.

Unfortunately, I cannot get it working, I succeded launching the same environment by doing so:

In the conda py35 env (64 bits)

```
import subprocess, json, shlex
arg1, arg2 = 1,2
args = shlex.split('python myScript.py {} {}'.format(arg1, arg2))
######################## Call subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
jsonData = stdout.decode()
data = json.loads(jsonData)
print(data)
```

In the file myScript.py supposed to run in the py34 env (32 bits)

```
import sys, json  
arg1, arg2 = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
out1, out2 = int(arg2), int(arg1) #out1, out2 = some_function(arg1, arg2)
jsonData = json.dumps({'out1' : out1, 'out2' : out2})
print(jsonData)
```

This example works and outputs what I want `{'out1': 2, 'out2': 1}` but `myScript.py` is not running within the 32 bits env, which is a requirement as I am going to use some legacy functions running only on 32 bits.

I tried to change the call to `subprocess` with the following:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(args, env = 'C:\Appl\Miniconda3_32bits\envs\py34\Scripts\activate', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Or with two following calls:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['CALL', 'C:\Appl\Miniconda3_32bits\envs\py34\Scripts\activate'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.communicate(args)

File "C:\Appl\Minconda3_64bits\envs\py35\lib\subprocess.py", line 955, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError
```

Or by changing the arguments:

```
args = shlex.split('CALL C:\Appl\Miniconda3_32bits\envs\py34\Scripts\activate python myScript.py {} {}'.format(arg1, arg2))
```

If you have any recommandations about how to get it working. I have only found previous questions about starting a new process within the same environment. I am quite puzzled about how to get it working and if my attempt is the best way to address this problem in a pythonic way.